# Как хранить в PhpMyAdmin специальные символы?

Tags: phpmyadmin, база-данных, php, mysql

Нужно хранить в БД символы наподобие таких:  `↓♫@{¥`

> Затронуто строк: 1. Warning: #1366
> Incorrect string value:
> '\xE2\x98\xBC\xC2\xA7\xE2...' for
> column 'password' at row 1

Такая ошибка пишется в БД.

И сохраняет примерно вот так ?§??

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову, колдовать с кодировкой таблицы.

Comment: У меня была похожая проблема http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446408/mysql-обрезает-текст-на-сложном-символе-картинке

Answer (score 2):

У меня такая же проблема была с сохранением emoji. Помогло изменение сравнения колонки в базе данных на `utf8mb4`. Возможно, и Вам оно поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сохранять `ascii` или `html` коды этих символов, преобразовывая при выводе.

Comment: мне так не нужно, надо что бы именно в таблице они хранились, коненчо не в таком виде а в том коде под котором они есть

Comment: тогда сохраняйте их в юникоде, проблем возникать не должно.

Answer (score -1):

Для этого есть прекрасная функция, которая "эскейпирует" все такие специальные символы для выполнения запроса. Прежде, чем выполнить любой запрос на вставку данных со специальными символами, выполните данную функцию:

```
   mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```

[Mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql_real_escape_string)