# MySQL обрезает текст на сложном символе-картинке

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Имеем текст

```
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">
Текст Текст Текст Текст
<img class="emoji" src="http://vk.com/images/emoji/D83DDCB2.png" alt="" />
</p>
```

При вставке в базу MySQL текст обрезается по символ , то есть остается

```
<p><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">
Текст Текст Текст Текст <img class="emoji"
src="http://vk.com/images/emoji/D83DDCB2.png" alt="
```

Вставка происходит в коде php:

```
$text = PHP_slashes($text); // экранируем кавычки
$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$this->table}` (`text`) VALUE ('$text')";
$this->db->execute($sql);
```

Попробовал вставить вручную в базу это сообщение - все сработало, только  заменился на `?`. Такое поведение вполне устраивает, можно бы и вовсе удалить такие символы из сообщения.

Аналогичная проблема на символах    и т.д.
Можно ли как-то поправить настройки базы или что-то сделать в коде php, чтобы такие символы переводились в `?` или удалялись ?

P.S.: Больше интересует не конкретное решение замены символов в строке, а настройки на все случаи  - чтобы база не резала текст, а как-то его сохраняла, заменяя непонятные ей символы.

Update: строка запроса

```
INSERT INTO `mails` (`text`) VALUE ('<p><strong><span style=\"font-size: medium;\">Текст Текст Текст Текст <img class=\"emoji\" src=\"http://vk.com/images/emoji/D83DDCB2.png\" alt=\"\" /></p>')
```

Только вместо  в текстовом файле отображается квадратик с вопросом

Comment: странно, что у вас вообще хоть что-то попадает в базу данных. надо ведь как минимум «заэскейпить» символы кавычек: `\"`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin они у меня экранированы, я просто не привел весь  код - счел, что он не относится к делу. Update: добавил соответствующую строку в код

Comment: а содержимое строки `$sql` вы не пробовали проконтролировать?

Comment: Да, покажите строку запроса как она выглядит уходя на выполнения. И надеюсь вы работает в кодировке utf-8? Включу режим телепата и предположу, что вам надо для всех таблиц в базе включить сравнение `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Comment: @Visman дополнил вопрос

Comment: Про кодировку, которую используете и сравнение в базе, что ответите?

Comment: У вас на этот символ `` аж 6 байтов на хранение отводится O_o

Comment: @Visman utf8_general_ci в базе, кодировка UTF-8

Comment: Если ваша версия mysql позволяет включите сравнение `utf8mb4_general_ci` в таблицах и в самой базе. Если нет, нужно mysql обновить.

Comment: @Visman там есть такой пункт, однако он автоматически изменяет его на  utf8_general_ci , Пробовал utf8_unicode_ci  - не помогло

Comment: MySQL какой версии?

Comment: @Visman версия 5.6.25

Comment: Странно, через Операции в phpmyadmin изменяется сравнение без проблем.

Comment: @Visman я делал через heidisql, но не думаю что это поможет, ибо utf8mb4_unicode_ci  не помогло

Comment: После коннекта к базе у вас наверное запрос уходит вида `SET NAMES 'utf8'` замените его на `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` или даже на `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'`

Comment: @Visman это надо просто выполнить как sql-запрос ?

Comment: Да, Обычно уже в движке этот запрос выполняется сразу после подключения к безе. Если у вас такого `SET NAMES 'utf8'` запроса ни где нет в коде, то можете выполнить один из предложенных мной вариантов сразу после подключения к бд.

Comment: @Visman `SET NAMES 'utf8'` не работает. `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'` и `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` работает - в базе `?` вместо символов фигурных. Теперь распишите в ответе что эта опция делает, почему просто `SET NAMES 'utf8'` не работает и я приму ваш ответ

Comment: Что значит `SET NAMES 'utf8'` не работает? :) Запрос этот работает и указывает, что соединение с базой идет в кодировке utf-8 с максимальной длиной символов 3 байта. `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` же указывает на ту же кодировку, но максимальную длину символов в 4 байта. Вот эти фигуристы символы, как и символы китайского и японского языков кодируются 4 байтами в кодировке utf-8.

Comment: @Visman а `COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'` что значит?

Comment: Сравнение задает, то которое я выше вручную предлагал для базы установить.

Comment: @Visman понятно. Для всей базы кстати я его теперь установил, для 1 таблицы не получалось

Comment: С использованием запроса `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'...` должно корректно работать и в таком случае.

Comment: @Visman ну вы оформите ответ. Меня теперь еще  интересует, что надо сделать, чтобы эти символы не в `?` превращались, а так и сохранялись в БД

Comment: То есть символы все равно нормально не отображаются? Значит надо таблицы и все столбцы в них с текстовой информацией конвертировать в сравнение `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27646/discussion-on-question-by-russcoder-mysql------).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша база сейчас работает в кодировке utf-8 в которой на 1 символ максимум выделяется 3 байта. Из-за этого ваши фигурные символы (а так же символы китайского и японского языков) не могут быть записаны в базу, так как имеют размер 4 байта.

Следует перевести базу данных на работу в кодировке utf-8 с поддержкой символов размером до 4 байт.

1. Если MySQL имеет версию ниже 5.5.3, его следует обновить.
2. Сделать полный бекап базы данных.
3. Для перевода базы на 4-x байтный utf-8 нужно выполнить команду

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE название_базы CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
   ```
4. Для каждой таблицы базы нужно выполнить команду такого вида

   ```
   ALTER TABLE название_таблицы CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
   ```
5. Для каждого поля содержащего текстовую информацию в каждой таблице нужно выполнить команду (примерный вид, зависит от структуры поля)

   ```
   ALTER TABLE название_таблицы CHANGE название_столбца название_столбца VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
   ```

   Пункты **3**-**5** можно выполнить например через phpmyadmin.
6. В код php нужно добавить сразу после коннекта к базе выполнение запроса вида

   ```
   SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
   ```

P.S. Про установку кодировки соединения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726863/186083

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю Вам вместо знака  и других подобных необходимо использовать [его код в html](http://takweb.pp.ua/ru/index.php), если html код приходит извне то парсить регуляркой так же по коду...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Не совсем то, что хотелось, но пока что работает, хотя я буду ждать более нормальные варианты.

```
function clearText($text) {
   $text = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251//IGNORE', $text);
   $text = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8//IGNORE', $text);
   return $text;
}
```

Эта функция убирает все "фигурные" символы из текста.

Решение типа

```
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//IGNORE', $text);
```

не работает.

Comment: Вы таким способом не только фигурные символы уберете, но наверняка и символы отличающиеся от латиницы и кириллицы.

Comment: @Visman да, скорее всего. Поэтому такое решение не самое лучшее, но вообще работает для моего случая