# Квадратные символы

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Mysql не принимает символы, похожие на квадратик. Где я беру такие символы? Захожу Вконтакт. Выделяю какой-нибудь текст со смайликами. Копирую в текстовое поле на своём сайте. Вместо смайликов вставляются в форму квадратики. Нажимаю кнопку отправить и Mysql выдаёт ошибку "incorrect string value xf0 x9f x98 x98".

В интернете пишут, будто надо выставить кодировку для таблицы `utf8mb4_general_ci`. У меня сейчас стоит `utf8_unicode_ci`. А в чём собственно проблема с `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: Видимо, это стоит посмотреть http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446408/mysql-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: А почему бы не взять их официальные коды, а-ля D83DDE0A, D83DDE03 и т.д. ? И работать непосредственно с ними