# Проблема с записью эмодзи в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql, vkontakte-api, mysqli

Здравствуйте! Я работаю с VK API, и мне нужно записать то, что написал пользователь, в базу данных. Проблема в том, что если пользователь отправит эмодзи, они заменяются четырьмя вопросительными знаками -- "????". То есть, если пользователь отправит "", в базу данных запишется "????". Кодировка БД -- `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Подключаюсь вот так:

```
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET NAMES utf8');
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET COLLATION_CONNECTION="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"');
```

Сам php-скрипт обрабатывает эмодзи нормально (пробовал отправлять пользователю в ответ его же сообщение -- всё ок).

Comment: А поле в таблице БД с какой кодировкой создано и какого оно типа

Comment: Создано с кодировкой `utf8_general_ci`, потом изменил на `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: В интернете говорят надо `SET NAMES utf8mb4`

Comment: Тоже самое, не работает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [MySQL обрезает текст на сложном символе-картинке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446408/mysql-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Всё, решил проблему! Я просто изменил запрос. Теперь он выглядит так:

```
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET NAMES utf8mb4');
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4');
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET COLLATION_CONNECTION="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"');
```

Comment: Аналогичная проблема, ни один из вышеописанных способов не помог. Гуглил несколько часов. Что примечательно - на одном компе (win10) с одинаковой версией mysql работает, а на другом компе (win7) - упорно превращает эмоджи в вопросы... Хотя кодировка базы и таблицы и подключения и вообще чего угодно - utf8mb4.